# Tag synonym request: [zorder] -> [z-order]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[Some poor fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461989/igor-milla?tab=activity) is busily correcting `zorder` to `z-order` without full edit privileges (so they have to be individually approved). Apparently I don't have the ability to add a synonym at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/z-order/synonyms . Would some kind soul please do so?

Even better: Add the ability to add any tag synonym to the new [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) privileges.

Comment: There are only 55 of them, and he's already half done :)

Comment: "Sorry, creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.". Arg. FAIL.

Comment: @VonC is there is a way to ask one of them (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/z-order/topusers) to do this?

Comment: @igor: only by leaving a comment on one of the answers from one of the two top users with 5+ rep.

Comment: I like the idea of adding this as a trusted user privilege, but I think that request should be put in a separate question.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: good point, thanks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges

Answer (score 1):

I was about to make the same request as I don't have enough privileges to ask for a synonym.

Currently, [`z-order`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z-order) has 68 questions, and [`zorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zorder) has 15. The `zorder` tag should be merged to the `z-order` tag as `z-order` has the tag wiki description attached to it.