# Add the ability to create any tag synonym to the "trusted user" privileges

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, trusted-user

Currently, the ability to create tag synonyms is limited to those users who have a certain amount of activity *in that tag*. This creates awkwardness for rare tags such as [[z-order]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78944/tag-synonym-request-zorder-z-order).

Request: Add the ability to create any tag synonym to the [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) privileges.

Comment: I've got that issue on the Apple sub site. There are some blatantly wrong tag synonyms that I still have to bug the elected moderators to correct.

Comment: Same problem on SU. If creating synonym suggestions and voting on them were possible for trusted users, we wouldn't need diamond moderator support for all those meta topics about tag synonym creation.

Comment: Related: [Can we allow 7.5K users to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag) My sentiments run as follows: pick a number, any number, *we need this feature*.

Comment: This is a long running bugbear over at GIS Stack Exchange too: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms