# Allow 10k users to *suggest* tag synonyms on new and developing tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Why can't 10k+ users suggest tag synonyms in tags that have very few questions?

Tags that don't have tons of questions yet (because they are new) are pretty difficult to manage, because *nobody* has enough rep to propose synonyms.

This is a problem, because the early days of tag development are crucial to setting the "officially recognized name".

---

**Edit:**
This seems to have been taken-care-of by the "Trusted User" privelege.
(Status-completed?)

Comment: I ran into a similar problem the other day when I wanted to vote on the [key-value-observing] tag to have [kvo] [be a synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/key-value-observing/synonyms), but found that only a small number of people had received votes on questions tagged with this.  I know exactly what the topic is, and it's been a topic of several questions I've answered (but not one of the tags).  It's just such an infrequently used tag that few people qualify to vote on it.

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges