# Tag synonym request: [belongsto] -> [belongs-to]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

[belongsto](/questions/tagged/belongsto) (0) -> [belongs-to](/questions/tagged/belongs-to) (143)

There were about five questions tagged [belongsto](/questions/tagged/belongsto), so I went ahead and retagged them. The synonym would just be to prevent future use.

---

<sub>Is there a better way to make synonym requests like this [when one doesn't have enough upvotes in a tag]? It seems cumbersome/awkward to create a meta question for something as trivial as this request. **Edit:** looks like this [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80225/allow-10k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-on-new-and-developing-tags) that would help.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A synonym would be useless. Typing "belongsto" and "belongs-to" yield the exact same results. Recreating the [belongsto](/questions/tagged/belongsto) tag is also prohibited now by tag creation rules.