# Tag synonym voting: set score threshold as the sum of scores on the synonym and master

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-score

Currently, a user can only vote on a synonym if s/he has xyz score on the *master* tag.

Now, many synonyms replace a more used but vague word with a more precise and less used word. A typical example would be [visible-light](/questions/tagged/visible-light)<--[light](/questions/tagged/light)  [on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/visible-light/synonyms).

I have the required score on [light](/questions/tagged/light). Shouldn't I be able to vote-to-synonym?

I propose that the voting/proposing requirements be set to the *sum* of scores on the master and synonym tags. Or something like that, at any rate.

Comment: How about we just [fix the problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag) with [the tag synonym voting process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges) outright?

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Yep, that too. On smaller sites like Physics, [getting a synonym approved is hard](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest). I don't see why the diamonds don't have a ninja-button to do so (they do have a merge button).

Comment: Well, they do... Diamond moderators have the privilege of creating a synonym with a single click. Same as a merge. Merging is just an option when you create the synonym, but not required. I just think the community should be able to be more active in the synonym creation process, rather than basically having to rely on a moderator.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Really? If you check the page I linked to, there's a pending synonym proposed by a diamond.

Comment: It's likely that he proposed the synonym before becoming a moderator. Either that or he didn't create it in the right place. I'm not actually sure if a moderator's synonym proposal in the standard UI is automatically accepted, or if they have to use the synonym-ator in the moderator tools.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: No, I suggested it to him in the first place. I'll ask him then--maybe he wanted to check out the community's response...

Comment: @TheEstablishment As moderator, I can propose a synonym in the page where users propose tags synonyms; I can also directly create a synonym in admin/create-tag-synonym.

Comment: @TheE yeah, he didn't want to moderator-synonym since it required a cleanup first.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128984/tag-synonym-score-of-5-rule-amendment